# how to pass password to sudo commands?

Tags: shell

on OSX I do

```
sudo route delete default
sudo route add default 192.168.178.1
```

to change my default gateway.

On running a sh file with these I am asked for a password every time. Which I run as

`sh changegw.sh`.

How do I pass my password before hand?

Comment: Instead of passing your password to the script, you could invoke the script with `sudo sh changegw.sh` or run `sudo bash` to get a root shell, then run your script from there. Then you won't need sudo in the script.

Answer (score 10):

For sudo there is a -S option for accepting the password from standard input. Here is the man entry:

```
-S          The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from
            the standard input instead of the terminal device.
```

This will allow you to run a command like:

```
echo myPassword | sudo -S ls /tmp
```

Comment: The downside is that your password is now in the shell history.

Comment: @rob You can prevent this pretty easily with the ignorespace trick. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5750144/490592

Answer (score 0):

While it is easiest to simply run the script as root, you could also create a group in the sudoers file that can run the program without a password, and add your username to that group.

I've never done this personally, though, and cannot recommend a specific line to add to your sudoers file.